# How can I use two property on form_widget

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I can show form by this codes.

```
$builder->add('icon', 'entity', array(
'class' => 'UserBundle:IconPics',   
'property' => ‘label', 'expanded' => true,    'multiple' => false, 
));
```

in twig

```
{{ form_label(form.icon) }}
{{ form_widget(form.icon) }}
```

There appeares radiobutton labeled 'PictureA' ,'PictureB','PictureC'....

But I want to use not only 'label' property but also 'pic' entity as well to make 
the link to jpg file.

How can I use two property via one form_widget?

My code are below.

I have tables such as

in User.php

```
  /** 
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Acme\UserBundle\Entity\IconPics", inversedBy="icon") 
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="icon", referencedColumnName="id",nullable=true) 
 */
private $icon;
```

in Icon.php

```
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 */

private $label;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 */
private $pic;

/** * * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Acme\UserBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="icon") 
* @ORM\JoinColumn(name="icon", referencedColumnName="id") 
*/
private $icon;
```

icon table is like

```
|id |pic     |label
|1  |aaa.png |pictureA
|2  |bbb.png |pictureB
|3  |ccc.png |PictureC
```

Comment: So basically your question is ... Using the entity field type - how to expose a second property (additional to the specified by the `property` attribute) of the underlying entity to the view? Please try to keep your questions a bit shorter and more general so they can help other people aswell in the future :)

Comment: yes,as you said, I want to use second property,but I am not sure how can I make it, in twig or in builder->add ? I will change the title and try keep it simple. thanks.

Comment: please see my answer - hope it guides you into the right direction :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might not be the most elegant solution but it's a quick one. The proper solution would probably be writing a custom field type which would involve writing a lot of code.

There is a simple trick to achieve what you want. Just add a method to your entity that will be used to get both values at once:

```
public function getFormViewData()
{
    return $this->getLabel() . ';' . $this->getPicture();
}
```

Then use this method in the `property` attribute:

```
$builder->add('icon', 'entity', array(
     // ...
    'property' => 'formViewData',
));
```

Finally use the twig [split filter](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/split.html) to separate get the two values in your template  (see the example) and adapt your template (i.e. by overriding the form_label widget ) to use these instead of the original value.

```
 {# 
    inside the overriden widget set the label correctly before rendering it 
    and extract the picture url.
 #}

 {% set label = label|split(';')|first|trans %}
 {% set picture = label|split(';')|last %}

 {{ label }}
 {{ picture }}
```

Got the idea?

Comment: It's great hint,I think I can understand the basic way of this. However I am using form_widget(form.icon). In this way ,I think I have to access each items of form.icon. I have no idea how can I access each item ...

Comment: Thx nifr,I think my general quesion 'how to use two property' is sloved.I made new article for another general  quesion.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19609624/how-to-access-each-items-of-form-widgetform