# How to access each items of form_widget(form.**)

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

How to access the each form item

```
$builder->add('icon', 'entity', array(
'class' => 'UserBundle:IconPics',   
'property' => ‘label', 'expanded' => true,    'multiple' => false, 
));
in twig

{{ form_label(form.icon) }}
{{ form_widget(form.icon) }}
```

it show this codes automatically and works well as radio button selector.

```
<div id="fos_user_registration_form_icon">
<input type="radio" id="fos_user_registration_form_icon_1" name="fos_user_registration_form[icon]" required="required" value="1" />
<label for="fos_user_registration_form_icon_1" class="required">pictureA.jpg</label>
<input type="radio" id="fos_user_registration_form_icon_2" name="fos_user_registration_form[icon]" required="required" value="2" />
<label for="fos_user_registration_form_icon_2" class="required">pictureB.jpg</label></div>
```

But I want to access each items in this code manually.

Since,I want to change code like this.

```
pictureB.jpg   -->  <img src="pictureB.jpg">
pictureA.jpg   -->  <img src="pictureA.jpg">
```

Is it possible??

Answer (score 2):

If you want to customise the way any form widget is rendered, you've then to override it. Take a deeper look at [How to customize Form Rendering](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html) section of the documentation.

You can find [here](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.3/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form/form_div_layout.html.twig) the default behaviour of all the form fields widget blocks. As described in the documentation, you've to,

- First, [know which block to override](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#form-template-blocks).
- Then, Override the block using [form theming](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#form-theming) (the documentation
  is full of examples whether you need to override your widget [only
  when a given template is concerned](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#method-1-inside-the-same-template-as-the-form) or [globally on your application](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#global-form-theming))